# How do I create lists in a list in Python? Is it possible?

Tags: python, list, char, brackets, letter

How to make list each character of list? like this:

```
li = ['A','B','C']
```

into :

```
li = [['A'],['B'],['C']]
```

Comment: `[[i] for i in li]`

Answer (score -1):

See "list comprehension".

It is simply,

```
[[i] for i in ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

or more generally,

```
[f(x) for x in list_name]
```